# What is the “run command console” (Alt+F2) in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I don’t quite understand what the run command console is, and I don’t understand two points.

1. There is a famous way to restart gnome-shell: Alt+F2 and then  “r” .
   What is this “r”?  Just an internal command of the run console? Then
   how many internal commands does the run console have?
2. I can execute my own scripts through the run console. However, I
   have to specify the full path, only then the script will work. If I
   use the shortcut ~/my-path/script, the script opens in the editor as the Display
   command in Nautilus. I don’t understand why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, 'r' is one of the internal commands in the run dialog. They're documented at https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet#Developer_tools.

- 'r' or 'restart': restart the shell
- 'rt': reload the shell theme (very useful when writing/modifying a theme)
- 'lg': open Looking Glass, which is the gnome-shell equivalent of DevTools in your browser
- 'debugexit': exits gnome-shell with an error exit code; probably only useful if you're doing development on the shell itself

For the second part, we need see exactly what the `_run()` function does in https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/main/js/ui/runDialog.js.

First, it handles the internal commands listed above.

Next, it parses the input with `GLib.shell_parse_argv()`, which just splits it into words like /bin/sh and doesn't do any kinds of expansion. It then tries to run the result directly with `GLib.spawn_async()`. This will search for the program in `$PATH`, which is why something like "firefox" works as you'd expect.

If that fails, it takes your whole input, expands '~' to your home directory, and tries opening it as a file.

Comment: Thank you, Eric